# Server does not send new stream via websocket after new release

Tags: ant-media-server-sdk

We had set a new server with [the last release](https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/releases/tag/ams-v2.2.1)

The issue is that when a user publish a stream video and that another one connects to room, the server sends streams via websocket to all new comer via the `streams` array sent with `joinedTheRoom` message. But when new comer join the room and start publishing, all the users that already are in the room does not receive the `streamJoined` message.

When looking at the server graphic interface, all streams are well published on the server, but it does not send the info via websocket. When logging all the received info from ws, we only receive `joinedTheRoom`, `initialized` and pings.

We used to have another server with the release 2.1.0, and we did not have such issues. We tried to see what have changed is the last release but most of the issues are empty. Can you see what went wrong with our server ? Do we need an updated version of Javascript SDK (if so, where can i find it ?) ?

Comment: It seems that `streamJoined` has been removed in August, and that is why I can't get it from the server. But how can I get the equivalent, a message/event that can warn every user in the room that a stream is available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, streamJoined has removed. You can check [here](https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/wiki/WebRTC-WebSocket-Messaging-Reference#conference-webrtc-stream) for further details.
Current implementation relies on client is getting room information from server every 5 second intervals.
So you need to change implementation from streamJoined to getroominfo.
You can check [here](https://github.com/ant-media/StreamApp/blob/master/src/main/webapp/conference.html) for new implementation of conference sample and i suggest you to look [here](https://github.com/ant-media/StreamApp/blob/master/src/main/webapp/js/webrtc_adaptor.js#L491) for updated Javascript SDK.
I guess if you look at new conference sample you can get it done.